# Is there any way to make an OptionMenu more navigable in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, dropdown, tkinter.optionmenu

So I´m doing a GUI app on Python with tkinter and my dropdown list (alphabetically ordered) is too long (+600 options). Currently the dropdown is created with OptionMenu, but it only has an arrow to go down on the list one by one.

Is there any way to make it more easy to navigate?

I´m thinking of something like common dropdowns where you type a letter and it takes you to the options that start with that letter. Or even a simple bar on the side to scroll down quickly, but any ideas are welcome.

```
root = Tk()
clicked = StringVar(root)
options = df['name'].tolist()
clicked.set(options[0])
dropdown = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options)
dropdown.pack()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `ttk.Combobox`, with `from tkinter import ttk`

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria that works a lot better, at least it adds the bar to scroll down. Thanks!